# problems with asynchronous data recording

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

there is a function code:

```
function fillingDataInCategory(categories, url) {
  let categoriesData = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
    conn.query(`SELECT product_id
                FROM products
                WHERE product_category_id = ${categories[i].id}`, (err, productInCategory) => {
      if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        fs.writeFileSync('api-reports-error-log.txt', 
          `${fs.readFileSync('api-reports-error-log.txt')}\n${url}: ${err} ${new Date().toLocaleDateString()}`);
      } else {
        console.log(productInCategory);
        categoriesData.push({category: categories[i].id, productInCategory: productInCategory.length});
      }
    });
  }
}
```

The problem is that an empty categoriesData array is returned due to asynchronous writing.
I haven't worked with asynchrony much, so I'll be happy to get any help.

Comment: You need to either: 1. Add a 'callback' argument to `fillingDataInCategory`, 2. Return a promise or 3. Use async/await

Comment: could you give me an example of the code, because I don't fully understand you?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a return at the end of your function, but I assume you want to return categoryData

I think that you are currently calling your function like this:

```
  function myFunc() {
    // Do stuff
    let categoriesData = fillingDataInCategory(categories, "myurl");
    console.log(categoriesData);
    // Do stuff
  }
```

First of all, I advise you to use forEach instead of for();

I suggest you to use a promise. And as you do multiple query in one function, use Promise.all

If the library you use to make your mysql calls allows it, use promises directly, but if it only allows you to make callbacks, convert that callback to a promise like this:

```
function makeRequest(categorie) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       conn.query(`SELECT product_id FROM products WHERE product_category_id = ${categorie.id}`, (err, productInCategory) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err) //reject at error
            } else {
                resolve({category: categorie.id, productInCategory: productInCategory /* You can put your .length here */}); //resolve with your result
            }
       });
    });
}
```

Here are the code that i wrote for you. I simulate your call do conn.query() with a delay of 1 sec

```
const fs = require('fs');

/* SIMULATE conn.query async call */

let conn = {
    query: (text, callback) => {
        setTimeout(callback(null, [1, 2, 3, 4] /* Return an fake array of result of length 4 */), 1000);
    }
}


function makeRequest(categorie) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       conn.query(`SELECT product_id FROM products WHERE product_category_id = ${categorie.id}`, (err, productInCategory) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err) //reject at error
            } else {
                resolve({category: categorie.id, productInCategory: productInCategory.length}); //resolve with your result
            }
       });
    });
}

function fillingDataInCategory(categories, url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let promiseList = [] //Make a array to fill with pending promise
        categories.forEach((categorie) => {
            promiseList.push(makeRequest(categorie)); // Adding a new pending request with the categorie inside the array
        })
        resolve(Promise.all(promiseList)); // Promise.all return a promise that take a list of pending promise
    });
}

function myFunc() {
    fillingDataInCategory([{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}], "myurl").then((categorieData) => {
        console.log(categorieData); //Now you get the resolve of the Promise.all
        //Do your post work
    }).catch((err) => { // If one of all the requests of the Promise.all array throw an error, then all requests fails
        //Do error stuffs
    });
    // Do stuff
}

myFunc();
```

and i get this :

```
➜  node test-stackoverflow.js
[
  { category: 1, productInCategory: 4 },
  { category: 2, productInCategory: 4 },
  { category: 3, productInCategory: 4 }
]
```